# Analyzing the work, critical path length and parallelism of algorithms

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, multidimensional-array, complexity-theory, mergesort

I'd like to know approaches on how to analyze the work, critical path length and parallelism of algorithms.

In particular, for solving the type of homework problems below:

[image: mergesorthomework]

[image: matrixhomework]

[image: matrixhomeworkagain]

In [Herlihy's book](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/134637/Herlihy,_Shavit_-_The_art_of_multiprocessor_programming.pdf), for example, they only show short formula's related on these kind of problems, but no explanations for the derivations are given:

[image]

Comment: This is a good question, but as you've phrased it as essentially "give me some references"... it's too broad and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it's asking for off-site resources. Can you edit the question to pose the specific homework problem directly, showing what you've done to solve it? In other words, don't ask for resources for solving problems "like X", just ask how to solve "X" itself (with your attempt). Thank you!

Comment: The merge sort question doesn't specify if memory is cached or not. If memory is not cached, the process will be memory bound (having to read code as well as read/write data), and multi-threading won't help. Multi-threading helps if each thread uses an independent cache. For example, each core on a X86 processor has it's own L1 and L2 cache, plus hyperthreading and a separate cache / pipeline for code. On a 4 core Intel 3770K processor, I got about 3x speed up on a 4 thread merge sort, and a 3.8x speed up on a 8 thread merge sort. More than 8 threads is slower than 8 threads.

Comment: @rcgldr Assuming it is with caching taken into account, as Herlihy's book is always assuming standard Intel processing behavior with all its concepts like caches, out-of-order executions, race conditions, memory fences, transaction memory, etc.

Comment: @Jover - ok, but the number of cores can vary from 4 to 8 on current X86 processors. With 8 cores, I assume 16 threads would be optimal for merge sort. I'm not sure analysis versus actual testing would show 16 threads to be a 7.6x speed up on an 8 core X86.